# Can't update hosts file on mac

Tags: macos, hosts

When I try to save changes made in /etc/hosts file on mac i get this error:

`"hosts" E212: Can't open file for writing`

How can I update it?

Comment: trying editing in in supersuser mode.  Like put "sudo" before the command.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the solution:

just use "sudo" before vi hosts (it will ask for administrator password). By doing this I, basically, open hosts file with Administrator privileges:

```
$ sudo vi hosts
```

and the after modifications `:wq` works just fine!

Answer (score 4):

Launch the Terminal

```
  $ sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

and after the modifications

```
 :wq!
```

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I was running `sudo vi etc/hosts` instead of `sudo vi /etc/hosts` ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: This happens when you hardly use the command line ¯_(ツ)_/.